# How to print a Java Swing UI which contains lots of component?

Tags: java, swing, printing, jcomponent

Requirement Description:

(1) I designed a UI with Java Swing Components which contains JTextFiled, JLabel, and JTable.

(2) The JTable was wrapped in a JScrollPanel due to UI size limitation.

Problem:

I wanna print the all the components with a "PRINT" button. But I am stuck by the JTable with the case that there are some rows in the talbe cannot be visible(which cannot be printed).

So what should I do about the JTable, or there is another way to print the whole components?

Thanks advanced, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) In order to be able to help, you need to show what you have tried so far, best in the form of an SSCCE (google to find out what that means)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to print the UI.  You want to print the contents of the `JTable`.

The `JTable` has an API for printing.  This tutorial might help: [How to Print Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html)